# Apply CSS Style inside ng-content

Tags: css, angular, sass, angular2-ngcontent

in an Angular application I have a component with `<ng-content></ng-content>`. I added the scss rules for content that will be put inside the ng-content, but they are ignored. I tried to solve using `:host`, but it doesn't work.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ewqhzj

Wrapper component:

```
<app-embed>
   <p>Hello world!</p><h1 class="toBeColored">toBeColored</h1>
</app-embed>
```

Styles in embed component:

```
:host {
  border: 5px solid red;
 padding: 15px;
 display: block;
 .toBeColored {
   color: pink;
 }
}
```

The problem is that the pink color of 'toBeColored' string is not set

Comment: Try adding encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native to your embed component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
:host ::ng-deep{
  border: 5px solid red;
  padding: 15px;
  display: block;
   .toBeColored {
    color: pink !important;
  }
}
```

and remove encapsulation statement and try ti build

```
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
```

Comment: It seems to work, but when I build in AOT I get the following error on '/deep/': An unhandled exception occurred: expected selector

Comment: You declare global all your css component where only `.toBeColored` need to be set global

Answer (score 1):

You can't achieve that with a clean way.

A workaround would be to create global css :

```
:host {
 ...;
 ::ng-deep .toBeColored {
   color: pink;
 }
}
```

But it will be deprecated. See this [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29765)

> ::ng-deep is going to hold the web record for long-lived deprecated API.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native to your embed component like

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-embed',
  templateUrl: './embed.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./embed.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.Native
})
export class EmbedComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: It seems to work but now I have the opposite problem, if in the <ng-content> I put some external styles (external to EmbedComponent) they are ignored

Comment: can you give more details and update the stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to apply the styles in the parent component that projects the content into the ng-content tag. The angular styles isolation appears to consider the content to be part of the component where the HTML is declared.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q9dn68